# arggroup with default value in picocli

Tags: java, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, picocli

Write cmd interface with Java code used picocli v4.6.3

My case:
./cmd [-a -b [-c]]

user put a,b option or got default value
example:

- user only put: ./cmd x1

  > a,b,c option got default value
- ./cmd x1 -a=a1

  > request input b option and vice versa (c option still get default value)
- ./cmd x1 -c=c1

  > a & b option get default value

```
@Command
public class CMD implements Runnable {

    @Parameters
    private String x;

    
    @ArgGroup(exclusive = false)
    private Group group;

    static class Group {
        @Option(names = "-a", required = true, defaultValue = "aa")
        public static String a;

        @Option(names = "-b", required = true, defaultValue = "bb")
        public static String b;

        @Option(names = "-c", required = false, defaultValue = "cc")
        public static String c;
    }
```

But it didn't work as I wanted
I didn't have the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer**

The picocli user manual has a detailed section on [assigning default values in argument groups](https://picocli.info/#_assigning_default_values_in_argument_groups).

Applications need to do both of the below:

- specify default values in both the `@Option` annotation, and in the initial value of the `@Option`-annotated field. (Yes, that means some duplication.)
- manually instantiate the `@ArgGroup`-annotated field

For your example, that means:

```java
@Command
public class CMD implements Runnable {

    @Parameters
    private String x;
    
    @ArgGroup(exclusive = false)
    private Group group = new Group();

    static class Group {
        @Option(names = "-a", required = true, defaultValue = "aa")
        public static String a = "aa";

        @Option(names = "-b", required = true, defaultValue = "bb")
        public static String b = "bb";

        @Option(names = "-c", required = false, defaultValue = "cc")
        public static String c = "cc";
    }
```

**Update (Answer #2)**

@kienbui pointed out that I missed these requirements:

> (...) if `-a` is specified, then `-b` becomes mandatory (user input becomes required), and similarly if `-b` is specified, then `-a` becomes mandatory. Otherwise, if neither `-a` nor `-b` is specified, none of the options are required and default values are assigned to the options that are not specified by the end user.

This can be achieved by making a separate inner arg-group for just options `-a` and `-b`, and removing the default values from the option declarations, but initializing them with their default values.
For example:

```java
@Command
static class CMD implements Runnable {

    @Parameters
    private String x;

    @ArgGroup(exclusive = false)
    private Group group = new Group();

    static class Group {
        @ArgGroup(exclusive = false)
        private InnerGroup inner = new InnerGroup("aa", "bb"); // default values

        @Option(names = "-c", required = false, defaultValue = "cc")
        public String c = "cc";
    }

    static class InnerGroup {
        // default constructor, used by picocli when
        // one or more options in this group are 
        // matched on the command line
        public InnerGroup() {}

        // this constructor assigns default values,
        // used only when *both* options are missing
        public InnerGroup(String a, String b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Option(names = "-a", required = true)
        public String a;

        @Option(names = "-b", required = true)
        public String b;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("a=%s, b=%s, c=%s, x=%s%n", 
                group.inner.a, group.inner.b, group.c, x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not fit my requirement.

Example:
./cmd -a a1
=> Need request user input b option, but your code used b option with defaul value

Comment: -a -b work as acc/pass option. If the user don't input anything, -a -b used default value, user can not input one of them,

Comment: I see... So, your requirement is that _if_ `-a` is specified, then `-b` becomes mandatory (user input becomes _required_), and similarly if `-b` is specified, then `-a` becomes mandatory. Otherwise, if neither `-a` nor `-b` is specified, _none_ of the options are required and default values are assigned to the options that are not specified by the end user. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes,  you are right

Comment: @kienbui I updated my answer. Hope this works better. :-)